# Kivy best way to schedule remove_widget

Tags: python, kivy

I want to remove my widget some time after an animation is played, otherwise the animation is practically unnoticeable if the widget is removed immediately after.
Hence, I tried using the following command, expecting the widget to be removed 0.5s after some animation:

```py
Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.remove_widget, k), 0.5)  # where k is my widget
```

But I get the following error, as Clock passes additional parameters to method:

```py
TypeError: remove_widget() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Is there some way to schedule widget removal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function must accept one positional argument, therefore

```
Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.remove_widget(k), 0.5)
```

is correct. But I recommand you another way.

```
def do_something_when_animation_ends(anim, widget):
    pass
anim = Animation(...)
anim.bind(on_complete=do_something_when_animation_ends)
anim.start(...)
```